# Query for fetching instance level metric for autoscaling group in cloudwatch

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-cloudwatch, dashboard

I am trying to write the query for fetching instance level metrics like mem_used_percent for a particular autoscaling group in cloudwatch dashboards. Is this possible via query? I don't want to manually select the instances annd hardcode the id's as this is an autoscaling group. While writing query, I see only aggregate metrics in the queries like SUM, MAX, MIN, COUNT, AVG etc. Can you connfirm if this is possible

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using the metrics explorer:
[image]

Comment: Thanks @Floh . It worked . is it possible that we cann club multiple metrics together to give a comaparative view like mem_used vs total_memory